# A theme has 3 default types posts, services and portfolio in its posts grid.I want to add my custom post type products How can I achieve that?

Tags: custom-post-types, archives

[image]

Here it display the dropdown list of options to be displayed in asri post grid. I have made my custom_post_type Our products which I want to be listed here.